# SF Connect Custom Adapter: upsertRows not called

Tags: salesforce-connect, externalobjects

I have implemented a custom adapter for Salesforce Connect - two Apex classes, one that implements DataSource.Provider, the other implements DataSource.Connection.  I have configured an External Data Source to use the adapter, and made the external object writable.

Almost everything works - I can query the external object, my custom Tab, list views, record detail pages, related lists all work.  I can even delete records.  But I can't update records.  I've put a "throw" into the "upsertRows" method, but it appears never to be called.

Has anyone seen this problem before?  (The code is deployed using API version 42.0.)

Code has been requested:

```
global override List<DataSource.UpsertResult> upsertRows( DataSource.UpsertContext context )
{
    System.assert( false, JSON.serialize( context ) );

    String sObjectName = 'XXX' + context.tableSelected + '__c';
    List<sObject> records = new List<sObject>();
    for ( Map<String,Object> recordFields : context.rows )
    {
        sObject record = (sObject) Type.forName( sObjectName ).newInstance();
        for ( String fieldName : recordFields.keySet() )
        {
            if ( fieldName != 'DisplayUrl' ) record.put( fieldName == 'ExternalId' ? externalIdField : fieldName + '__c', recordFields.get( fieldName ) );
        }
        records.add( record );
    }
    List<DataSource.UpsertResult> results = new List<DataSource.UpsertResult>();
    for ( Database.UpsertResult result : Database.upsert( records ) )
    {
        results.add
        (   result.isSuccess()
        ?   DataSource.UpsertResult.success( result.getId() )
        :   DataSource.UpsertResult.failure( result.getId(), result.getErrors()[0].getMessage() )
        );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding the relevant Apex from your update method - this is currently in the close queue for lacking relevant code

Comment: I've posted the code for the upsertRows method.  The assert will throw an exception if the method is called.  The exception is not thrown, so I conclude that the method is not called.